# Addition and Subtraction of Dates in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date

How can we add or subtract date in java? For instance `java.sql.Date` and formatted like this: *yyyy-MM-dd*, how can i Add 5 months from that? I've seen in some tutorial that they are using `Calendar`, can we set date on it? Please Help.

Example: `2012-01-01` when added 5 months will become `2012-06-01`.

*PS: I'm a .Net Programmer and slowly learning to Java environment.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all you have to convert your `String` date to `java.util.Date`, than you have to use `java.util.Calendar` to manipulate dates. It is also possible to do math with millis, but I do not recommend this.

```java
public static void main( final String[] args ) throws ParseException {
    final String sdate = "2012-01-01";
    final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    final Date date = df.parse( sdate ); // conversion from String
    final java.util.Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime( date );
    cal.add( GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 5 ); // date manipulation
    System.out.println( "result: " + df.format( cal.getTime() ) ); // conversion to String
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Stear clear of the built-in Date class for date math. Take a look at JodaTime, which has a much better API for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
```

Comment: Sir what does `getInstance` do? How can i set cal to `2012-01-01`?

Comment: `getInstance()` is a factory method it would initilize calendar with current date and time of system, you could use `setTime()` method to set any date, see java doc

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118370/10819573) uses `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in 2012. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern date-time API:

**You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` for your date string:** `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format e.g. your date string, `2012-01-01` which can be parsed directly into a `LocalDate` instance, that contains just date units.

Having parsed the date string into `LocalDate`, you can add or subtract different date units e.g. years, months, days etc. to it.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2012-01-01");
        System.out.println(date);

        LocalDate afterFiveMonths = date.plusMonths(5);
        LocalDate beforeFiveMonths = date.minusMonths(5);
        System.out.println(afterFiveMonths);
        System.out.println(beforeFiveMonths);

        // Alternatively,
        afterFiveMonths = date.plus(5, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
        beforeFiveMonths = date.minus(5, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
        System.out.println(afterFiveMonths);
        System.out.println(beforeFiveMonths);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2012-01-01
2012-06-01
2011-08-01
2012-06-01
2011-08-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Cap1fI)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a Date to a Calendar, use:

```
Date date = your_date_here;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Then use the calendar arithmetic functions to add/subtract:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, Convert the date to time in milis. Do the math, and convert the millis back to a date.

Answer (score 0):

use `CalenderUtils` from google's package GWT.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil;
```

...

```
//now
Date d = new Date();
// Now + 2 months
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(d, 2);
```

Comment: Your proposal to add 5 months to a date is to add the whole of GWT to a project?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) class from the 3rd party Apache Commons library collection.  Example:

```
Date d = DateUtils.parseDate("2012-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d2 = DateUtils.addMonths(d, 5);
System.out.println("Old date + 5 months = " + d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways. One of them could be with *joda.time*.
*This does not answer the question by using *Calendar* but one of the other approach if needed by someone. :D*

```
import java.sql.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
//
DateTime datetime = new DateTime("2012-01-01");
Date dt = new Date(datetime.plusMonths(5).toDate().getTime());
System.out.println(dt);
// This gives output as 2012-06-01
```

PS: *Happy coding with Java*

Comment: Not bad if someone does need a `Date` in 2022 (or later). Which shouldn’t be the case, though, since the `Date` class is long outdated and poorly designed, nothing that anyone should use any more. Also, while Joda-Time was a good library, it has now been officially replaced by java.time, the modern Java date and time API. See [the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74984006/5772882).

Comment: You are right. joda.time is replaced by java.time (they even ask you to migrate to this). It was used before the release of Java 8 and as this was an old question from 2012, I answered it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score -1):

The complete program that does date addition is in http://dwbitechguru.blogspot.ca/2014/09/jave-program-to-add-or-substract-dates.html

Comment: as @Parixit pointed out, normally we try explain the big lines of links like that. If the link ever goes down your answer becomes useless for the community. If you could edit it to add the important parts, it would make a valid answer :) thx ^^