# Convert string form JDateChooser into date

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextfield, jdatechooser

I am searching for a small week now for this little problem;

1. I want (the user) to input a date in JDateChooser or JTextField, but im not sure if that works with calendar value in the JTextField.
2. Add 3 month and 45 days to it (to the user given date).
3. Display the the calculation on the screen (with System.out.printn or JLabel).

example. user inputs (01-04-2010) add months/days(3 months, 45 days) output
 on the screen (15-08-2010).

i cant find any tutorial about this :( 
Hope someone can help me a little bit further

Comment: Can you please share the code you've already written so we can see what are are doing right and/or wrong?

Comment: `Calendar cal = Calendar.getTime (dateChooserCombo1);
        cal.add (Calendar.MONTH, + 3);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, + 45);
        System.out.println("new date:" + (cal));`

Comment: I think you'll find what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118327/addition-and-subtraction-of-dates-in-java

Comment: Thank you very much, i think i can figure it out for now.